# Getting an Uncaught TypeError in ChromeAPI.js on every page I load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, typeerror

Every page I load in Chrome (Version 38.0.2125.101) throws this error in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined    (chromeAPI.js:1)`

Full stacktrace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined ChromeAPI.js:1
    initAPI ChromeAPI.js:1
    (anonymous function) CoreAPI.js:1
    q.execCb cajon.js:1
    b.check cajon.js:1
    (anonymous function) cajon.js:1
    (anonymous function) cajon.js:1
    (anonymous function) cajon.js:1
    each cajon.js:1
    b.emit cajon.js:1
    b.check cajon.js:1
    (anonymous function) cajon.js:1
    (anonymous function) cajon.js:1
    (anonymous function) cajon.js:1
    each cajon.js:1
    b.emit cajon.js:1
    b.check cajon.js:1
    b.enable cajon.js:1
    b.init cajon.js:1
    h cajon.js:1
    q.completeLoad cajon.js:1
    (anonymous function) cajon.js:1
    n.onreadystatechange cajon.js:1
```

Comment: Do you have any addons loaded? Does it do the same in incomgnito?

Comment: @qwertymk You're right, it looks like it's caused by the StayFocusd addon in Chrome, thanks!

Comment: Here is the related bug ticket: https://getsatisfaction.com/stayfocusd/topics/getting-an-uncaught-typeerror-in-chromeapi-js-on-every-page-i-load

Comment: Could one of you - either qwertymk or the question author - add the relevant parts of the question's comments as answer and mark it solved so the question does not remain open? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @qwertymk the bug was being caused by an add-on in Google Chrome, which has since been patched.